# Book information: designed, produced, published, and printed

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference, word-in-context

I have an art book under my hands, but am, because of my curiosity, struggling to understand the difference between:

- designed
- produced
- published
- printed

I thought the first two and last two were the same thing. Are they not?

[image: mentioned book information]

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not involved in book publishing and therefore these definitions may not be technically correct. They are based on my lay-person's understanding.

**Designed:** Who prepared the visual aspects of the book, the illustrations and general design.

**Produced:** Who oversaw the rest of the production of the book, typesetting, arranging pages and producing the file for printing. This is a rather unusual phrase if you ask me (British English speaker) and I haven't really encountered it applied to books before.

**Published:** Who has the rights to the edition (not the content, as that has a separate copyright), who hired the designer, producer and printer, who oversaw the whole process of getting the book from someone's head onto the paper that you are holding.

**Printed:** Where the book was literally put on paper, where the pages were printed.